# Binding ion-checkbox values with initial checked values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I have some `ion-checkboxes` inside a `ng-repeat` that has some **checkboxes checked** initially. I can't seem to manage to bind these initial values on form submit. Here is what I'm working with so far:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list>
        <label ng-repeat="item in items">
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="itemCheck(item)">
                {{item.name}}
            </ion-checkbox>
        </label>
 </ion-list>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.items = [{name:"name1"},{name:"name2"},{name:"name3"},{name:"name4"}];
$scope.itemCheck = function(data){
    $scope.checkedItems = [{name:"name2"},{name:"name3"}];
    $scope.checkedResult = $scope.checkedItems.filter(function(item) {
            return item.name == data.name;
    });

    if ($scope.checkedResult.length > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/pixeloft/pen/LLboWG?editors=1000

Answer (score 0):

It is weird to use `ng-model` and `ng-checked` together.

I only use `ng-model` and I have no problem.
Just keep your model simple: instead of `$scope.checkedItems = [{name:"name2"},{name:"name3"}];` why don't you just set the check attribute of each item?

Initialize your items like this:
`$scope.items = [{name:"name1"},{name:"name2", checked: true},{name:"name3", checked: true},{name:"name4"}];`

Answer (score -1):

Try this way.

HTML

```
<ion-list>
        <label ng-repeat="item in items">
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="itemCheck(item,$index)">
                {{item.name}}
            </ion-checkbox>
        </label>
 </ion-list>
```

JS

```
$scope.items = [{name:"name1"},{name:"name2"},{name:"name3"},{name:"name4"}];
$scope.itemCheck = function(data,index){
    $scope.checkedItems = [{name:"name2"},{name:"name3"}];
    $scope.checkedResult = $scope.checkedItems.filter(function(item) {
            return item.name == data.name;
    });

    if ($scope.checkedResult.length > 0){
        $scope.items[index].checked=true;
        return true;
    } else {
        $scope.items[index].checked=false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tested in codepen and it works!
I really don't know if it's this you're looking for but let me know!